# Beginners MySQL Doubts

Tags: mysql

I've started learning PHP with MySQL and come across some preliminary doubts. Hope someone helps clarify them..

1. I've come to know that there is a default user account named 'root' with no password. I changed the default password. Now, using command prompt when I try to login to mysql using `C:\xampp\mysql\bin\mysql` it returns me with the default `MariaDB[(none)]` prompt, but won't let me create any database, unless I login using actual password I set as: `C:\xampp\mysql\bin\mysql -u root -p` after which it prompts me to enter my password.
   Also, it doesn't display the databases I created from within the root user account when I use the command `show databases;`

Is there a way to enter the required password from within the `MariaDB[(none)]` prompt mode? or do I have to manually `exit` and re-enter using `mysql -u root -p` ?

2. Should I have separate user account per project?
3. How is phpMyAdmin related with this user account, because it never asked my password?

Thanks in advance. Will come up with more doubts as I go on.

Comment: Use a MySQL GUI IDE (like SQLYog community) much eazier then the console prompt.

Comment: Ok. Thanks Raymond. Is phpMyadmin a similar tool? I am also trying to understand the underlying working hence the cmd prompt.